# convert seconds to hour and min format

Tags: postgresql, time, apache-superset

I have a column that return seconds from a task and I'd like to convert it into hours and minutes
Example: if the column has 16200 seconds  I'd like to get the result as 4h30m

Also, need to get sum of all the values as hr and min,....sum(column name)=sum(hr)sum(min)

Comment: `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(16200)` => `'04:30:00'`

Comment: No match found for function signature SEC_TO_TIME(<CHARACTER>)

Comment: CONCAT(FLOOR(minutes/3600),'h ',MOD(minutes,3600),'m') is there any way to write a query in this format.This query is for converting minutes to hr and min same way i need to convert seconds to hr and min

Comment: @dkasipovic please help

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL and not Postgresql?

Comment: select paidDurationInSeconds, 
CONCAT(FLOOR(paidDurationInSeconds/3600),' h ',MOD(paidDurationInSeconds/60,60),' m') 
FROM tickets               This is the correct query i am able to get but now i need sum of paidDurationinSeconds to sum hr and min

Comment: @GRIV guess it is postgresql---apache druid

Comment: What's the column's data type? What is 16200 being stored as?

Comment: Also, please update your tag from mysql to postgresql

Comment: @GRIV it is string

Comment: Thanks for updating the tag, please see my answer and see if that helps. I've accounted for string/numeric values.

Comment: @GRIV using the query gives error:   Error: SQL parse failed

Encountered ":" at line 1, column 41. More...

org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(durationInSeconds::interval), 'fmHH24hfmMIm') FROM tickets

Answer (score 2):

If your *seconds* column is a `numeric` type, you can use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((16200 || ' second')::interval, 'fmHH24hfmMIm')
```

If its a `string` type, use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('16200'::interval, 'fmHH24hfmMIm')
```

Of course, replace 16200 with your appropriate column name.
Precede HH and MI with `fm` for **Fill Mode**. This will remove the preceding zero values from hour and minute.

Output:
**4h30m**

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b5f00a111b149fed99bfce6c8b93130b).

To get the `SUM` of all values, add the `SUM` function to your seconds column like so:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(seconds_column::interval), 'fmHH24hfmMIm') FROM test_table
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7279f43c1711650784843892bd4870c6).

Comment: how to get sum of all the values as hr and min,....sum(column name)=sum(hr)sum(min)

Comment: Please update your question to include that, you only asked for the conversion of seconds into hours/minutes.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `SUM`, but I would advise editing your question to make it more clear what you're asking. Your question may be viewed many times in the future by many people, so its important to create a clear question with examples, etc. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) for more information.

Comment: using the above query gives error:  Error: SQL parse failed

Encountered ":" at line 1, column 41. More...

org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException

Comment: Can you add the query you tried to your question?

Comment: I ran your query under your question comments. It works fine for me. Is there something wrong with your column you're using, should it be paidDurationInSeconds instead of durationInSeconds (based on your other comment query)? If that's not the problem, please revise your question. We need more sample data and your table structure or create a fiddle like I did so we can see exactly what's happening.